# Running Magento project from PhpStorm

Tags: magento, phpstorm

I have downloaded magento project from my ec2 instance. I have just downloaded the magento root directory folder and imported into the phpstorm. Now how do I run that project. Where do I setup server and database  settings. How to deploy the project

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Tutorials -- all tutorials are here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and create a database of your choice. Then just go to your browser and run your localhost/projectname/index.php. It will ask you for all the requirements and install your project right there.

Comment: But I have database already running on my remote server. I need to be able to use that. The remote data can be accessed via ssh tunnel

Comment: just give the url of your database in your local.xml